# JavaFX LineChart loop values

Tags: javafx, linechart

Somehow my chart does not want to get values from loop.
The bufferedReader gets values from file and is splitted into parts with ";". The String[] parts list is field variable.

```
XYChart.Series series = new XYChart.Series();
for(int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(i, parts[i]));
        }
```

If I put System.out.println into loop, then the values are printed out correctly.

With ordinary values, the program works correctly.

The console puts out java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException.

Comment: Please post the complete stack trace, enough code to reproduce the problem, and indicate which line is throwing the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get the answer myself.
The XYChart data cannot be String list type, but double or int.
Is there any way to make String[] list to double[] list ?